# How to cache the new user post with php Memcached?

Tags: php, memcached

I have Social engine system like facebook or SocialEngine ...  User home page shows thier friends posts, and their activity. I want to cache this home page for reduce mysql server loading for ex in the user home page exist 10 post so we have a scenario like this  :

```
if cached is exist 

   show homepage cached // fo 10  new post

else
  homepage db query // fetch 10 new post
  cache homepage to memcache // we cache it for 5 minitues
```

I have a problem :
 One of users friends write one new post , so when user refresh home page he cannot see a friend new post until 5 minutes , Is there a way that automatically update cache when a homepage has been updated ??

Comment: What you're looking for is cache invalidation upon writing. Basically, what you do is remove the entry from the cache as soon as it changes. This forces the next request to retrieve the data from the database, after which it will be cached again. You can take this one step further, and do what is known as write-through caching, where you overwrite the cache with the updated values you just inserted in the database.

Comment: "I want to learn how to do X, let's start with a crappy copy of facebook". I'd say learn to crawl before trying to drive spaceships, man.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to automatically update your cache. In fact this is a very common issue known as *cache invalidation*.

Either you can use basic cache invalidation via the [Memcached::delete()](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.delete.php) method. This will cause the cache to be re-generated the next time someone visits the (un)cached page.

Or you can utilize write-through caching, which means you do what is necessary to update the page and then save the new result to the old cache key, the same way you would save it if you visited the page. This solution tends to be far more complex.

Also, see [kander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151847/kander)'s excellent comment.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky situation you have here, and I can see two ways of going about it.

1) You hold a cache entry for each individual user with their friends posts on (e.g. Memcache entry under the key "User1" which would contain an array of 10 items, "User2" => "post content", "User8" => "post content", etc) which would require you to update all of the user friends memcache entries when they make a new post.

2) You hold a cache entry for each individual user with their posts on (e.g. Memcache entry under the key "User 1" which would contain an array of the users most 10 recent posts, "postid" => "post content", "timestamp", "content" which would require you to update the users individual cache of their 10 most recent posts, but whenever one of the users friend loads the homepage, that users friend would have to query all of their friends caches and compare the timestamp on their recent posts to the current timestamp.

I would use solution 2.